# Cohen And the Bodies Exhibit

Tags: tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, kohen-priest

Can a Cohen Visit the [Bodies Exhibit](http://www.bodiestheexhibition.com/) or is Tumah: Ritual Impurity a concern?

Comment: There's an additional question of whether anyone should visit that exhibit, for reasons other than tum-a.

Comment: Yes and that is addressed here:

http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/724709/Rabbi_Daniel_Stein/'Bodies'_The_Halachah_-_Viewing_Dead_Body_Parts

Comment: And Here:

http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/724358/_Rebecca_Marmor/The_Bodies_Exhibition:_Educational_Experience_or_Modern_Day_Side_Show?

Comment: Are the exhibits in their own glass cases?

Answer (score 2):

I asked my Rabbi about this a while ago, and he agreed with me that it's assur for anyone, Cohen or Yisroel,  to go to the Bodies Exhibit (other than medical students). The exhibit displays desecrated human bodies, and it would be assur to go be entertained by it. If a Cohen is a medical student, then for pikuach nefesh he (along with any other medical student) would be allowed to go, but only for the purpose of studying the bodies, not just to see "art" or be "entertained".

Comment: Who said a Cohen can be a medical student?

Comment: Medical students spend a fortune in tuition, and one of the things that money goes to is cadavers they get to dissect themselves. I don't expect that there'd be much additional benefit to observing one of these necro-entertainment exhibitions.

Comment: I can see the exhibit being beneficial for a medical students as it could help them to visualize the entire human body, including parts they normally wouldn't dissect, in three dimensions and in positions they wouldn't normally see a cadaver in.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that one could assume that the bodies are of non jewish, meaning it has no tuma

Comment: Who said non-Jewish bodies don't have tumah? See Shulchan Aruch YD 372:2

Comment: IIRC its still metame binegia just not beohel. Even then, the Shulchan Aruch writes that a cohen should not walk over non-Jewish graves; there's a chashash that even being ma'ahil is an issue